# send/receive messages using one socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am reading a bunch of messages from a table one by one, send it to a server, receive response for every request and  save that response in another table.

I am using a socket to do it (java) that works fine. My problem is that I want to use only one socket or one stream to treat all the messages one by one.

I am using this method for the receiving part, the first message comes by ok but always a problem for the second one as of the bufferReader is blocked or something.

I have to use the Read()(where the code is breaking already) call because i can not use the readline() call.(the server java version is 1.4)
the main problem is that once the socket in production,multiple connection are established while i want only one that handles all the messages

Example of the message

```
52147523101090131125000199000080808078123456123456789125000074125896`
```

Example of the response

```
104587596548521475231010901311250001990000808080781234561234567891250000741258960000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000055555
```

This is my code:

```
public String decrypt(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < 165; i++) {
        int ch = br.read();
        if (ch == -1) {
            throw new IOException("truncated message: Probleme avec la lecture du reponse serveur");
        } 
        sb.append((char) ch);
    }

    String message = sb.toString();


    return message;
}
```

Comment: Your examples are confusing as it's not clear what your expectation and actual results are. br.read() blocks (it stops if there is no further bytes to be read, until more bytes become available or if the connection is blocked).  If you want to know if it is safe to read() without hitting a block, call ready() first to ask the reader if it's safe. 

None of the code you posted decides whether one or multiple sockets are created. So not much can be said about this. You are saying that you want only one socket used. Serverside you will always have multiple sockets, 1 per client.

Comment: i'am sorry i couldn't explain more,but long story short, my program is reading from a DB table,asking response for every ligne in the table and then saving the response in another DB table. i'am using socket for this. the problem is  i want to use only one socket for all the messeges that iam going to send @Joeblade

Comment: @Joeblade, the programe works fine if i open and close a socket for every message but if i do it one time in the code, the first message go through but it blocks in the posted Method for the second message$